# How to add SQL user-defined function to Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, function

I want to add a SQL function to Entity Framework 5 database-first, but when I updated the model, my function does not show up in the update wizard window.

I'm trying to add this function this way:

```
Add New > Function Import
```

but does this does not work, either.

My question: how can I access this function?

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/moozzyk/CodeFirstFunctions ?

Comment: not this for codefirst and my entity is database first.

Comment: Still works with DB first, if you combine with: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/blob/master/EntityFramework.Reverse.POCO.Generator/Database.tt#L39

Comment: Procedural code (like functions) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.